# Using SP result (with/without LINQ) to get Paged results

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, paging

I am working with MVC 4 EF (DB first approach). In the database, I am using an SP that gives me this Paged result (basically a list with a pagesize of 5):

[image: result]

The problem is I don't know how to use this with LINQ to get paged results. I have googled & SOed all the related stuff in the last 3 hours. Haven't quite found what I need.

How do I use a Stored Procedure (in the area encircled) to get Paged results and also to pass input parameters (pageno., pagesize, sortcol, sortorder, etc)?

[image: question]

Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
        const int pageSize = 10;
        string Name = null;
        string Description = null;
        string sortCol= null;
        string sortOrder= null;
        var model = db.spTempItemSubClassList(Name, Description, sortCol, sortOrder, page, pageSize).ToList();
       return View(model);
```